# How to close an active panel in a jQuery Accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All I'm trying to do is close the active panel, however it won't do that, and I can see it's something to do with my jQuery. It's working perfectly, except that function of being able to close the active one.

At the moment it's working great at being able to open only one panel at a time so I'd like to keep this as is. I'm sure it's something simple!

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

 
   $( "#accordion").on('click','.accordion-heading', function (e) {
            $return = true;
            if($(this).next('div').is(':visible')== false) $return = false;
            $( "#accordion .panel2").slideUp();
            $("#accordion  .accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('div').stop(true,false).slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return $return;
        });




});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::before{
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {

  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel2 {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" ">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the current panel has the `active` class or not. If it has, then just toggle it and close the panel. Otherwise do what you did.

Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#expand").change(function() {
       if (this.checked) {
           $("#accordion  .accordion-heading").addClass('active locked');
           $('.panel2').slideDown();
       } else {
           $("#accordion  .accordion-heading").removeClass('active locked');
           $('.panel2').slideUp();
       }
   });
   $("#accordion").on('click','.accordion-heading', function (e) {
      if (!$("#expand").prop("checked")) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
              $(this).next('div').slideUp();
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          } else {
              $("#accordion .panel2").slideUp();
              $("#accordion  .accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
              $(this).next('div').stop(true,false).slideDown();
              $(this).addClass('active');
          }
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::before{
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {

  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel2 {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="expand" type="checkbox">Expand all
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you so much! You wouldn't happen to know how to get all the panels to expand when the page is in edit mode i.e. for a publishing or wiki page for SharePoint? somehow when the page goes into edit mode you can't edit the panels without having to go to Edit Source which I know will confuse our site owners to the max.

Comment: @clare I've added an example of expand all checkbox. Try it. And if the answer was helpful, please accept it)

Comment: I just tried that in the SharePoint edit mode and it won't expand them. I can't click to expand at all. If you have any other tricks I'd love to hear them. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @clare unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SharePoint

Comment: No worries! Thanks for all your help! You are truly wonderful and have saved me!!